# Complexity of using postMessage() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, xss, postmessage

I am trying to enable communication via JavaScript from an iframe and its parent window when they are on different domains. I did a lot of research and it turned out that postMessage() is a good approach if used correctly. I have read the vast resources about how to use it to make sure it’s implemented in a secure way and came up with the below code. However, as I am still new to coding, I am paranoiac about XSS vulnerabilities and this code looks too simple to me to be secure. I haven’t found a clear post on Stack Overflow about the simplicity/ complexity of using postMessage().

Context:

- The message must be sent from the iframe to the parent window only
- The iframe is https, while the parent is http
- The message doesn’t contain sensitive data – it’s just a simple indicator for - - The parent window to do trigger a google analytics event
- Parent window domain is: `http://my-main-web.com`
- Ifame domain is: `https://my-iframe-web.com`

Questions:

- Is the below code exposed to security risks?
- In case it is, are there other risks apart that the attacker might find out the message content is ‘download occurred’? E.g. can he inject meticulous code through the message?

Sender (iframe):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  parent.postMessage("download occurred", "http://my-main-web.com");
</script>
```

Receiver (parent window):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function receiveMessage(event) {
    if(event.origin !== “https://my-iframe-web.com”) return; // validate origin

    if (event.data !== "download occurred") return; // validate message content
      console.log(“msg received”);
      // trigger GA event
    };

  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>
```

Thank you!
Mihai

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The code is fine. And yes, it is that easy.

Comment: thank you guys for the input. I did not know about code review stackexchange, will look into it. Thanks